# How to add Html tags with sprintf function

Tags: php, html, wordpress, printf

I want to add HTML tags with `sprintf` function. I want to inject HTML tags with "Has been added to your cart" but HTML is also getting printed on screen. Any leads? Thanks!

My code is below:

```php
$titles = array_filter( $titles );
/* translators: %s: product name */ 
$added_text= sprintf( _n('%s Has been added to your cart', '%s ', $count, 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );
  
// Output success messages.
if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
  $return_to = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wc_get_raw_referer() ? wp_validate_redirect( wc_get_raw_referer(), false ) : wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) );
  $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" tabindex="1" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> <span id="cart-message-text">%s</span>', esc_url( $return_to ), esc_html__( 'Continue shopping', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
} else {
  $message = sprintf( '<a href="%s" tabindex="1" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ), esc_html__( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
}

if ( has_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message' ) ) {
  wc_deprecated_function( 'The wc_add_to_cart_message filter', '3.0', 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html' );
  $message = apply_filters( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', $message, $product_id );
}

$message = apply_filters( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', $message, $products, $show_qty );

if ( $return ) {
  return $message;
} else {
  wc_add_notice( $message, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_notice_type', 'success' ) );
}
```

Comment: `sprintf` is incidental. I suspect that when your messages are being output they're being encoded with `htmlspecialchars()`. You haven't shown that part of your code.

Comment: I have edited code now. You can check please

Comment: What **exactly** is going wrong with the given code? What have you tried to fix that problem?

Comment: Code is working perfectly, i just want to add html tags to text "has been added to your cart"

Comment: You're escaping HTML code on your own code. Two times you use the function `esc_html($added_text)`.